# Can't stop rendering on android

Tags: android, android-intent, opengl-es

I want to stop the game when my character has died and then switch from the game into a game over screen. but I found that I find a problem that the start activity isn't recognized

```
   if(!player1.isDestroyed){
        scrollBackground1(gl);
        scrollBackground2(gl);
        movePlayer1(gl); 
        moveEnemy(gl);
        detectCollisions(gl);
    }
    else{//to the gameover screen
        Intent end = new Intent(SFEngine.context, GameOver.class);
        startActivity(end);
    }
```

this code is from the renderer which the class is implement renderer, NOT Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent end = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver.class);
        startActivity(end);
```

Comment: the getApplicationContext() isn't recognized as well

Comment: the problem is that i want to switch from a renderer into an activity, i dont think i can use intent anymore, or maybe there's another trick